# Using Schröder-Bernstein theorem to show same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Use the Schröder-Bernstein theorem to show that $(0,1)\subseteq \Bbb R$ and $[0,1]\subseteq\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality.

Firstly I'm not even entirely sure about what the syntax even means. The elements of subset (0,1) and [0,1] are also included in the set of all real numbers? And [0,1] doesn't include 0 and 1 but (0,1) does? Even when I understand the syntax I probably won't know how to solve it

Comment: By definition, $$(0, 1) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 < x < 1\}$$ while $$[0, 1] = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \le x \le 1\}$$

Comment: Ah I see, so how can I show they have the same cardinality?

Comment: Now that you know what $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ are, perhaps you should think for more than a minute about how to show that they have the same cardinality.

Comment: I really have no idea how to show two infinite sets have the same cardinality

Comment: Do you know what the Schröder-Bernstein theorem says?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(0,1) \subset [0,1]$ so $|(0,1)| \le |[0,1]|$.

Using the bijection $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2} x$, we see that $|[0,1]| = |[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]|$, and since $[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}] \subset (0,1)$ we have $|[0,1]| = |[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]| \le |(0,1)|$.

Hence, using the Bieber-Cantor–Bernstein–Schröder-Heimlich-Presley theorem we have $|(0,1)| =|[0,1]|$.

Comment: A historical note: Justin Bieber's proof, though very popular with the young ladies, ultimately turned out to be flawed.  Therefore his name is sometimes omitted from the theorem.

Comment: I am laughing like crazy at your name for the theorem!

Comment: I think he helped Heimlich at a restaurant once. Not sure about the Presley-Bernstein connection, though :-).

Comment: Too much maths. makes Joe a dull boy!

Comment: Joe is the bar owner of my favorite Irish pub in Vienna. He's a great guy, and now with my local regular pub closed... I miss that Viennese pub. (Oh, I thought that we were already beyond the point of writing arbitrary things in the comments now...)

Comment: So the bijection can be replaced by any other? like 1/6 + 1/3 x?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Broke that rule a long time ago. In my even less erudite InterRail days, I missed out on a trip to Vienna because, unfortunately, it was spelled Wien. Maybe catch up with you sometime when I finally arrive :-).

Comment: @Foxic: Well, within reason, you need to make sure that the bijection maps the set $[0,1]$ into $(0,1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Well, I'm not there anymore. I only clocked like five weeks there until now (and hopefully one week in the coming July), but I still managed to become regular in three different pubs. It's sort of my superpower.

Comment: @copper.hat: That is as old as 12 years, two months and eight days now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sorry, I am very slow. I just computed. Definitely need some alcohol.

Answer (score 5):

They intend to indicate that $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ are meant to indicate intervals of the real line. Then $$(0,1)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid 0<x<1\}$$ and $$[0,1]=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid0\le x\le1\}.$$

If they had said instead that $(0,1)\subseteq\Bbb Q$ and $[0,1]\subseteq\Bbb Q,$ for example, then they would be talking about *rational* intervals, instead--that is:

- $(0,1)=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid 0<x<1\}$
- $[0,1]=\{x\in\Bbb Q\mid0\le x\le1\}$

What you need to do is demonstrate a one-to-one function $(0,1)\to[0,1]$ and a one-to-one function $[0,1]\to(0,1).$ The first of these tasks is very straightforward, and the second is only slightly less so. Once these tasks are done, Schröder-Bernstein Theorem tells us that the two intervals have the same cardinality.

Comment: Clearly Schröder and Bernstein are hiding many, many points under an excluded middle carpet...

Answer (score 4):

First you need to understand the notation, $(a,b)=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a<x<b\}$ and $[a,b]=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a\leq x\leq b\}$.

Then you need to understand the problem. You need to use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem in order to show that there exists a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Then you need to understand what is the Cantor-Bernstein theorem. The theorem states: If there are injective functions $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to A$ then there exists a bijection $h\colon A\to B$.

So to use it you need to exhibit two injections. One injection from $[0,1]$ into $(0,1)$ and one from $(0,1)$ into $[0,1]$. I will leave this part to you.

Comment: +1 for outlining all the things that need to occur within the OP's mind, as well as in the actual execution of the proof.